# How do I escape a field variable in an awk command in an alias?

Tags: escaping, csh

Here are the contents of a file:

```
one two three
four five six
```

And here is my alias

```
alias testawk "awk '{print $2}' file"
```

This is what I get:

```
> testawk
one two three
four five six
```

But when I give this command, then I get what I want:

```
> awk '{print $2}' file
two
five
```

How do I escape the field specifier in the alias? NOTE: I'm using csh

Comment: Here is an explanation on dealing with csh meta-chars http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-7

Comment: `\$` works in bash, but csh is a bit more finicky.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Wrap the alias w/ `'` and use `'\''` for the embedded `'`.

```
alias testawk 'awk '\''{print $2}'\'' file'
```

Comment: I didn't see that you were using csh first. This corrected answer should work for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I hate all those little quirks of csh.  Its too bad I'm forced to use it here at my work.